# В продолжение(и)

Tags: лексика

Ситуация такая: есть две части статьи. 
«В продолжении(е) статьи мы расскажем о…»
Какое в данном случае окончание? Я думаю, что -и. Ведь имеется в виду именно в самом продолжении, а не «в ходе (процессе)».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы рассказываете о статье-продолжении, то будет так:

> В продолжении статьи мы расскажем о…

Если, например, вы планируете выступление на конференции, где, помимо данных из статьи, будут новые данные, то можно сказать и так:

> В продолжение статьи мы расскажем о…

Answer (score 1):

Да, это существительное, так как нельзя заменить На 'в течение'.

Comment: А что, "в продолжение", все гда можно заменить на "в течение"?
"В продолжение телефонного разговора высылаю вам документы".
Тут "в течение" никаким боком. Если уж на что и менять так на "продолжая".

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже так думаю. Здесь "в продолжение" - существительное с предлогом,  а не составной предлог. Позволяет вставить определение, например: "в готовящемся продолжении".

ЗЫ Вообще мне кажется, что роль предлога "в продолжение" сильно преувеличина. Его по привычке частенько находят там, где имеет место именно существительное.

Comment: Быть может, так происходит оттого, что здесь тонкая грань: вроде бы можно так, а вроде - и по-другому :)

Comment: Ну насчёт грани - это ничего не объясняет. Да, она тонкая, но почему эту грань всегда "переступают" именно в эту сторону? Опять же за предлогами "в течение", "в заключение" и т. д. такого не водится.